# In linux how can I create a folder from a file?

Tags: linux, file-management

I ran the following command to find all epubs and move them to a directory:

```
find . -iname "*.epub" -exec mv {} /data/EPUB \;
```

That created a super file with all the epubs concatenated together. Is there any way to break them apart again? Is there a command to change the super file into a folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you did not create the directory `/data/EPUB` first then effectively what you did was rename each file, one at a time, to a file named `/data/EPUB` - overwriting the previous one each time.

What you have now is not a "superfile", rather `/data/EPUB` is the final .epub file that was moved, and all other .epub files have been lost (as they were overwritten by subsequent moves).

There is no straightforward way to retrieve them.

I suggest unmounting the device immediately (if possible) and performing no further writes, then using a program such as [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to attempt to recover the overwritten files (also detailed instructions [here](http://www.linux.org/threads/undelete-files-on-linux-systems.4316/)).

In the future I recommend using `mv -i` which will prompt for overwrite, thus catching any mistakes such as this one.

I also suggest making a habit of placing a trailing `/` after directory names, which will also catch such errors by failing if the directory does not exist (rather than assuming it is a file), e.g.:

```
find . -iname "*.epub" -exec mv -i {} /data/EPUB/ \;
```

Comment: ++++1 whenever you use the move command ALWAYS use a trailing slash.  Even advanced linux admins can get bitten by this (ahem ahem) because for example we create backup scripts that copy files to datestamped directories.  Guess what?  A new year comes around and I forget to create a directory (or rather forget to put error checking in the script to create the directory if it doesn't exist) then all your backups will get written over because a directory wasn't created.